# Python 3: ordering keys in specific order in objects within an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, ordereddict

I currently have some code which walks a JSON file, takes each object and sorts the key value pair alphabetically by key. Certain keys are inserted at the front of the order, specifically name and description.

```py
def walk_json(data, first=False):
    if isinstance(data, (dict)):
        if not first:
            data = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items()))
        for key, value in data.items():
            data[key] = walk_json(value)

    if isinstance(data, (list)):
        for index, item in enumerate(data):
            data[index] = walk_json(item)
    return data


def validate_json(filename):
    fp = None
    data = None

    try:
        fp = open(filename)
    except OSError:
        print(f"\nERROR {filename}\n")
        return

    try:
        data = json.load(fp, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    except ValueError:
        print(f"\nINVALID {filename}\n")
        badJSON.append(filename)
        return
    finally:
        fp.close()

    if data is None:
        print(f"EMPTY {filename}")
        return

    ordered = OrderedDict()
    if "display_name" in data:
        ordered["display_name"] = data["display_name"]
    if "description" in data:
        ordered["description"] = data["description"]

    ordered.update(sorted(data.items()))
    data = walk_json(ordered, True)
```

I have another file which is an object with a single key, `build_list`, which is an array containing multiple objects. I have failed to figure out how to perform the same operation as above, but for each object within `data["build_list"]`. The keys are sorted alphabetically within each object, but I have been unsuccessful in trying to pin the key `"name"` to the start of each object.

The code isn't mine, so I won't pretend I fully understand it. I'm just trying to adapt it slightly.

Comment: As a side note, it is terrible programming practice to require strict ordering of dictionary keys.  JSON doesn't care, and there's no reason why your code should care.

Comment: It's simply about maintaining an identical order between files, since this is all content that humans will work on. If every file has the same set of keys but they're all in different places that makes it much harder for people to work on them. Having a name key first in the object for example makes a file much more readable for people.

Comment: I'm just being obstinate here, but one can argue that humans shouldn't be regularly dinking with JSON data anyway.  There should be a friendly UI that makes mistakes less likely.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def reorder_keys(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        new_obj = OrderedDict()
        for key in key_order:
            if key in obj:
                new_obj[key] = reorder_keys(obj[key])

        for key, value in obj.items():
            new_obj[key] = reorder_keys(value)

        return new_obj

    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return list(map(reorder_keys, obj))

    return obj


# Format all the AI files and reorder the object keys
for file in Path("server/pa/ai").glob("**/*.json"):
    data, warnings = pajson.loadf(file)
    list(map(print, warnings))

    data = reorder_keys(data)

    with open(file, "w") as f:
        f.write(pajson.dumps(data, indent=2))
        f.write("\n")
```